# SSIS/SSMS Connection to SAP Reports/Transactions

Tags: ssis, ssms, etl, sap-erp

I am not familiar with SAP systems, but I have user access to an SAP instance that allows me to access, for example: transaction code **FB03**.

I have been reading on the internet on possible ways to connect via SQL Management Studio or SSIS to SAP Tables, which I know it is possible, but my question is, it possible to somehow extract these t-code data directly into management studio or ssis?

Can I query tcodes directly into SSIS OR SSMS ? If so, how is it done?

It might be quite a newbie question, but once again, not familiar with this system.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Can I query T-CODES directly into SSIS OR SSMS?

Nope. They are executed only via SAP client aka SAPLogon.

> > I have been reading on the internet on possible ways to connect via SQL Management Studio or SSIS to SAP Tables,

It is done directly via SQL Management Studio if you know SAP DB Instance host and have access credentials/permissions for it. Usually regular users do **not** have them, only BASIS staff.

> > is, it possible to somehow extract these t-code data directly into management studio or ssis?

Nope, this is raw data, which is then aggregated and showed in SAP transactions (tcodes) in some (business-)readable form, so access to SAP DB data and access to tcodes is **not** the same. You need to know how to interpret this data.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification :)